# Metric for reliability of a software system

Tags: metrics

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Software_reliability_testing#Measurement) it should be :

[image: forumula]

But I am not sure what should the values be for `t` and `e` or how it can be calculated with values substituted. Any help navigating this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

t is time and [e is the Euler number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)), approximately 2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995.

[image]

You can then use the [MTTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures) (in the same period (month, second, year) as t) and get the reliability metric.